# Teradata SQL to group by hour interval out of a TIMESTAMP(6)

Tags: sql, datetime, intervals, teradata

I am looking to use Teradata to group volume hourly over a date range when 'time' is a timestamp(6)

```
SELECT VOLUME, HOUR(time)
FROM table
GROUP BY HOUR(time)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no HOUR function in Teradata, according to Standard SQL it's EXTRACT:

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestampcol)
```

And of course you need a aggregate function, but i assume VOLUME will be the alias for a SUM/AVG/COUNT  :-)